# How to compile ioping with cygwin

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cygwin

Using Cygwin on Windows 7 x64. Extracted 'ioping' source into '/home'

This is the result:

```
$ make
test ! -d .git || git describe --tags --dirty=+ | sed 's/^v//;s/-/./g' > version
cc -std=gnu99 -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -DVERSION=\"0.8\" -c -o ioping.o ioping.c
ioping.c: In function ‘get_device_size’:
ioping.c:602:3: error: #error no get disk size method
 # error no get disk size method
   ^
Makefile:46: recipe for target 'ioping.o' failed
make: *** [ioping.o] Error 1
```

Trying to compile a Windows executable. I'm new to Cygwin. Seems like a preprocessor is missing when looking at the code.

Source: https://github.com/koct9i/ioping

Edit:
See accepted asnwer user, 'user3629249' and my comments for full answer.

Note of the linked source. 'Readme' says it works on windows, Tried running it on Win 7 Ultimate 64-bit with SSD and it errors out with "preparation write failed: no error".

Comment: you really should NOT have placed the ioping project files in your `home` directory.   rather,  create a sub directory.  Then place the project files in that sub directory.

Comment: I was terse for simplicity at the time, but I actually put it in it's own dir, just didn't show it above, just wanted to point out what seemed like was the most relevant base dir. But yes for posterity, it should be located in a sub dir for organizational reason. Some may see as nitpicking, but a good point none the less.

Answer (score 0):

the function: `get_device_size()`  selects certain `ioctl() depending on the underlying OS.

which `ioctl()` depends on which of the following are defined at `make` time

1. `__linux__`
2. `__gnu_hurd__`
3. `__FreeBSD__`
4. `__FreeBSD_kernel__`
5. `__DragonFly__`
6. `__OpenBSD__`
7. `__APPLE__`
8. `__sun__`
9. `__MINGW32__`

Browse your environment variables

I would expect some environment variable like `__cygwin__`

Which ever environment variable seems most likely to be the appropriate one, add the name of the environment variable to the sets of preprocessor blocks near the top of the `ioping.c` file and again in the `get_device_size()` function.

Comment: Simplest solution for me was installing standalone 'MinGW'. From what I read it would have taken some work to get it working with Cygwin(Didn't want to take chance of messing up Cygwin environment settings as I use it for other things) Thanks for the attempt.

Comment: the utility `MinGW` is for windows, not a unix like environment.   The only changes would be within the oping.c file not in the cygwin environment.  however, if you do not want to change the *.c file, then in your .bashrc file add statements similar to `set __linux__ `  and `export __linux__`